# vue.js - display html fetched from a link

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, widget

I'm trying to display html from a link. the idea is to host some html in a file on github or other site and have it render in a widget in my vue.js app (not just display the html code)

The code currently allows for a text area in the interface to be populated with some text or regex that is then displayed in the widget. the idea is to be able to put a URL in that text area and have it load the html.

I am very new to vue.js and would really appreciate some help pointing me in the right direction.

```
<template>
  <!-- The template section is where you design your widget using HTML -->
  <div>Using text interpolation: {{customregex}}  <span style="color: red">This should be red. {{customregex}}</span></div>

  <!-- <div><span v-html="customregex"></span></div> -->
</template>
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the v-html directive?

Comment: @jkoch thanks for the reply. yes i have. i tried putting in the v-html directive within the div tag but it just displays the URL as opposed to the html

Comment: v-html doesn't fetch the html for you. It renders the html in the string. Maybe you want to use an iframe.